# global function and class reference

Tags: c++, class, oop, global

I want to send integer value in class to global function from main. How should I send it as a parameter,I am sending the parameters wrong

```
Tetris
{
private: 
    int num;
}

printBoard(Tetris &t);

int main()
{
    Tetris tetris;
    printBoard(board,tetris);
}
```

i want to send num , to printboard.

Comment: Add a getter method to Tetris `int get_num() const noexcept { return num; } and change `printBoard` to `void printBoard(const Tetris& t)` if you don't want printing to be able to change the state of your board.

Comment: You're also missing the `class` keyword when defining the class. Also you're missing the return type from the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the shown code.

**First**, you're missing the `class` keyword when defining the class.

**Second**, the return type of the function is also missing.

**Third**, the function has only one parameter but you're passing two arguments.

---

> i want to send num , to printboard

You can add a getter called `getNum` which you can use from inside your free function as shown below:

```
vvvvv------------->added this class keyword
class Tetris
{
private: 
    int num = 0; //don't forget to initialize 
    public:
    //add a getter 
    int getNum() const 
    {
        return num; //return a copy
    }
};
vvvv----------------------->added return type as void
void printBoard(Tetris &t)
{
    std::cout << t.getNum(); //use the getter 
}

int main()
{
    Tetris tetris;
    printBoard(tetris);
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Gn9Y3ckSA)